# Get the default server in php

Tags: php, nslookup

When I enter nslookup at the cmd prompt, it tells me the default server.

How do I retrieve that information using PHP?

The server it returns is not the same server that the PHP is running on (or for that matter the nslookup is running on).

I know I could shell out and run nslookup and parse the output, but that doesn't seem very robust (ie. what if the output changes format in future versions of nslookup).

Comment: Are you asking how you can find the IP address for a given hostname using PHP?

Comment: No, I don't have the host name - That's what I'm after.

Comment: The hostname of what? If I type `nslookup`, then I get a `>` prompt.

Comment: I get the `>` prompt too, but after it has told me the default server that it is using.  This highlights my robustness issue :-)

Comment: Default server for what?

Comment: The one that nslookup connects to by default

Comment: For what purpose does it connect to that server? What kind of server are you trying to find?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I then want to use that server to do an ldap connect

Comment: Now I'm really confused. nslookup is a DNS tool. The default server it connects to will be a DNS server, not an LDAP server.

Comment: Possibly you are working in an environment where the same computer is hosting a DNS and LDAP service, which brings us back to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: As for XY problem - I need to authenticate against active directory, but I need the host to be able to do that - that host just happens to be the default server that nslookup shows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Default Server" is your primary DNS server. Getting the default DNS server directly with PHP is not possible.
From your further infos after Quentin asked, you dont look for the DNS Name.
If it is a Server where you logon with f.ex. Windows, this could be the right answer:

```
echo getenv("LOGONSERVER");
```

Otherwise your solution with exec and parsing the output will be the best. Maybe you could use `ipconfig /all` for that and look for the DNS or DHCP server, depends on your environment.

Comment: getenv("LOGONSERVER") returns a different server than shown in nslookup, but, that host also works for the ldap connection - don't understand why, but it works so don't care why :-)

Comment: The LOGONSERVER-Variable contains the NetworkName of the Server, where the nslookup command returns the Hostname that resolves to an IP. So this will only work if you are logged in on this Server and are in the same LAN.